# Multiple Web Client ID support when designing back-end services with Google Sign-in, use cases

Tags: android, google-oauth, google-signin

I am trying to figure out what the use-cases are for allowing multiple Web Client IDs in the back-end for an Android app that uses Google Sign-in. Per docs [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth) it's possible to verify audience against multiple Web Client IDs. What would be the use for having multiple Web Client IDs for a singular back-end?
I suppose you could use it to manage access if you had different clients that accessed the same back-end, but signed with different Web Client Ids. At the same time, wouldn't you just remove the OAuth Client IDs associated with the client you are trying to revoke access to instead?
Basically, I am generally confused by this example:

```
    GoogleIdTokenVerifier verifier = new GoogleIdTokenVerifier.Builder(transport, jsonFactory)
    // Specify the CLIENT_ID of the app that accesses the backend:
    .setAudience(Collections.singletonList(CLIENT_ID))
    // Or, if multiple clients access the backend:
    //.setAudience(Arrays.asList(CLIENT_ID_1, CLIENT_ID_2, CLIENT_ID_3))
    .build();
```